# How to redirect in nginx without using rewrite?

Tags: nginx, redirect, redirection

Can someone tell me how I can redirect x.domain.com to www.domain2.com in nginx without using the rewrite module/functionality?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the rewrite module?  That's what it's there for.

Comment: I considered down-voting also, but then I realized they may not have access to the server's configuration (unlikely, but possible).

Answer (score 1):

In Nginx alone, impossible.  Outside of Nginx, you could use an HTML page with a meta-redirect or use PHP to send a location header.

Comment: Ok. That's all I needed to know. Why did you down-vote my question?  Who do you think you are?

Comment: I didn't down vote the question.  Why didn't you accept the answer?